# Loading 3d model in cocos3d

Tags: ios, cocos3d, 3d-model

I'm new to cocos3d and I've read some information about loading 3d-models into cocos3d. The native way to add 3d-models in cocos3d is, as I understood, to convert models got from Blender or from 3DsMax into POD format via convertors. Is not it seemed a bit difficult? In my app I can easily do this as I've got few models, but assume I'm writing a big game with hundreds or thousands models, should I do the same? Convert every model I have? Is it a good practice?

Thanks!

Comment: 3D engines without tools and asset pipeline will be a big pain, more so the more complex your project is. Consider switching to Unity which takes care of all the asset management issues.

Comment: As much I understand, POD is closed source and proprietary file format for chip maker who made GPU for iphone. So probably Collada2POD tool will remain as main conversion tool and there are often extra conversion step to get Collada out of your favorite 3D authoring tool and then have to drag-drop them into XCode. I hope future brings better tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, maybe this answer will be useful to someone. I've written few scripts to automate getting 3d models from my 3d designers (they are using Blender). The first one is to export .blend files as .dae, it is written on Python, files should exist in one directory (see argument list in next scripts):

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import bpy

if len(sys.argv) != 7:
    print("Must provide input and output path")
else:
    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(sys.argv[5], '*.blend')):
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
        bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=infile)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True,rotation=True,scale=True)
        outfilename = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(infile)[1])[0] + ".dae"
        bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath=os.path.join(sys.argv[6], outfilename),apply_modifiers=True,include_armatures=True,deform_bones_only=True,include_uv_textures=True,include_material_textures=True,active_uv_only=True)
```

the second one is to export these .dae files to .pod with Collada2Pod, this is Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $dir = '/Users/nikita/Develop/model_convertor/dae_models/';
my $out_dir = '/Users/nikita/Develop/model_convertor/pod_models/';
my $collada = '/Users/nikita/Develop/model_convertor/Collada2POD/MacOS_x86_32/Collada2POD';

opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

    next if ($file !~ m/\.dae/);

    $out_file = $file;
    $out_file =~ s/dae/pod/g;

    $command = "$collada -i=$dir$file -o=$out_dir$out_file";
    system($command);
}
```

usage example:

```
/Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender --background --python /Users/nikita/Develop/model_convertor/exporter.py -- /Users/nikita/Develop/model_convertor/catalog /Users/nikita/Develop/model_convertor/dae_models

perl /Users/nikita/Develop/model_convertor/convertor.pl
```

where the first command is "/path/to/blender --background --python /path/to/first/script -- /path/to/blend/files /path/to/dae/files". The second command is simply perl script execute. Sorry for hard coding constant variables in the second script :) Hope that would be useful to someone.

Update: I've added `transform_apply` function into first script, since there were problems with models without applied transforms, which caused wrong ones in output

Comment: Thanks for the code, but after done, the file format is dae not pod.

Comment: @Dio no, the file format is pod. As you can see, the first script is exporting file as dae from Blender, and the second script is launching Collada2Pod convertor, so the result format is exactly what we need - pod.